# Property initializer syntax in ESnext

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

I understand there is a TC-39 proposal for a new syntax called "property initializer syntax" in JavaScript `class`es.

I haven't yet found much documentation for this, but it is used in an egghead course when discussing React.

```
class Foo {
  bar = () => {
    return this;
  }
}
```

What is the purpose of this proposal? How does it differ from:

```
class Foo {
  bar() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

Comment: Because it's a property, and not a class method, you can bind `this` to the function, which the arrow function does automatically.

Comment: Àrrow function vs. traditional function...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use property initializer syntax with an arrow function, `this` in this function will always refer to the instance of the class, whereas with regular methods, you can change `this` by using `.call()` or `.bind()`:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.test = true;
  }
  bar = () => {
    return this;
  }
}
console.log(new Foo().bar.call({}).test); // true

class Foo2 {
  constructor() {
    this.test = true;
  }
  bar() {
    return this;
  }
}
console.log(new Foo2().bar.call({}).test); // undefined
```

Also, this syntax can be used for other things than functions.

Answer (score 0):

From a different angle, you can use the Property initializer syntax as a shorthand for otherwise verbose method binding in constructor.

*Also notice that the syntax can be used for variables as well.*

```
class Property {
  v = 42

  bar = () => {
    return this.v
  }
}
// --------

class Bound {
  constructor() {
    this.v = 43
    this.bar = this.bar.bind(this)
  }

  bar() {
    return this.v;
  }
}
// --------

class Classic {
  constructor() {
    this.v = 44
  }

  bar() {
    return this.v;
  }
}
```

,

```
const allBars = [
  new Property().bar,
  new Bound().bar,
  new Classic().bar
]

console.log([
  allBars[0](),
  allBars[1](),
  allBars[2]()
])

// prints: [42, 43, undefined]
```

Property `v` is undefined in the allBars array where the `this` of unbound `bar` points since it was called from its context.